# how to manage dropdownlist event change in MVC 4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I am very newbie to ASP.NET MVC 4. I am still learning new things around in MVC. I have been google around to find a solution but I dont understand their code. Im bit confused. So I decide to write here as my requirement. There is a dropdownlist with a list of Vendor and Status. So when you select value "Vendor", the dropdownlist event should fire to pass value in javascript to make textbox visible otherwise invisible. My code doesnt work when I try to fire the event pass to javascript. How to solve this problem? Your full example code much appreciated. thanks

**Index.cshtml**

```
    @Html.DropDownList("Direction", new List<SelectListItem>
  {
     new SelectListItem{ Text = "Vendor", Value = "0" },
    new SelectListItem{ Text = "Status", Value = "1" } 
  },new {onchange = "showTextBox(this)"})
   }

 @Html.TextBox("txtVendor") //how to make this invisible?
 @Html.Label("lblStatus")


 <script type="text/javascript">
    function showTextBox(item) {
    if (item.value == "Vendor") {
        document.getElementById('txtVendor').style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
    else if (item.value == "Status")
    {
       document.getElementById('lblStatus').style.visibility = 'visible';
    }

}
</script>
```

Comment: Is your `<script>` in the `<head>`?

Comment: `function showTextBox(item) {alert('yes')}` can you see whether the function gets executed using some alert

Comment: in the head? not sure how to to do this. maybe you can give me an example code...

Comment: @user235973457: Within the HTML, you have a `<head></head>` section. That `<script></script>` should be placed there when binding to `on*` events using attributes (e.g. `<sometag onchange="" onclick="">`)

Comment: @BradChristie He's probably using layout template, so not going to see all that unless you look in _layout or master page

Comment: The item.Value should match the values of each `SelectListItem` (`Value = "0"`)

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net MVC works on "name" attribute and not on "id". When you create an element with @Html.TextBox("txtVendor") only name attribute is added, there is no "id" attribute added to the control. You can check this by viewing the page source of page in the browser.

To make the controls visible/invisible you need to either use document.getElementByName('ele_name') or use input tag with id attribute to create the element.

Comment: This is incorrect, at least for MVC 4/Visual Studio 2012, where both the name and the id attributes are populated in the output.